# Paramiko change IP of remote machine

Tags: python, paramiko

I have to change the IP of a remote machine running Gentoo. For this I use a code that looks like

```
try:
    guest.connect("10.22.254.200", username='root',password='root')
    except SSHException as detail:
        session.flash = detail.message
    else:
        sftp = guest.open_sftp()
        sftp.put('./scripts/change-ip', '/root/change-ip')
        sftp.close()
        guest.exec_command('chmod +x /root/change-ip')
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            stdin,stdout,stderr = guest.exec_command('/root/change-ip 10.22.254.200 &')
```

My change-ip script looks like

```
set -x
cp /etc/conf.d/net  /etc/conf.d/net.bak
sed "s/10.22.254.200/$1/g" /etc/conf.d/net.bak > /etc/conf.d/net
/etc/init.d/net.eth0 restart
```

I am able to ssh directly and execute the script successfully changing the ip, but for some reason cant do it in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Restarting the network might lead to bad surprises, as the restart command might be killed. Does using `nohup` on the restart command solves the problem ? If not, can you give us some more information (like putting echo on every line of the script to see what is executed and what is not) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I did what you suggested.. To be exact, I did "stdin,stdout,stderr = guest.exec_command('nohup /root/change-ip '+guest_ip+' > /dev/null 2>&1 &')"

Comment: Since I got the solution, should I close this? or should I post the solution as a solution??

Comment: You should post the solution and accept the answer. If it is what I suggested, do you mind if post the solution myself ?

Comment: Not at all! go ahead and post!, It was really your solution!!

Comment: Here we are. Thank you !

Comment: Should be me thanking you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the network over the network is a dangerous thing. What happens here is that after stopping the network interface in the command `/etc/init.d/net.eth0 restart` the script receive a `HANGUP` signal stating that the connection has been closed, and stops before starting the network interface.

To avoid this problem, you can use `nohup`, which "run a command immune to hangups".